# How to display category and list

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to php and mysql. I want to display the category and it's list. And I want it to happen like this. Please help me. I'm really stuck to it.

My Database table:

[image]

**How it is now:**

[image]

**How I need it**

- Book

  - Math
  - Physics
- Gadget

  - Cellphone
  - Laptop
  - Power Bank

My code:

```
$getitems = mysql_query("SELECT category, 
                                name 
                           FROM items_for_checking 
                          WHERE status = 'approved' ");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($getitems);

if($numrows > 0){
    $row       = mysql_fetch_assoc($getitems);
    $category  = $row['category'];
    $name       = $row['name'];
    $last       = $category;

    echo "<div class='cat'>
              <div class='cat-head'>
                 CATEGORY
              </div>
              <div class='main-cat'>
                  <li>$category<li>
                  <ul>
              </div>
              </div>
          </div>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getitems)){
    $category    = $row['category'];
    $name        = $row['name'];

    if($last != $category){
        echo "</ul><li>$category</li><ul>";
    }
    echo "<li>$name</li>";
    $last = $category;
}
echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? This isnt `do the code for me`   site.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: yes. i have tried it

Comment: You can easily achieve this by table and loop the data from your the database.

Comment: @Ven can you provide the example of where you have tried it so we can help improve and/or correct where you went wrong.

Comment: Why are you using mysql functions rather than mysqli or PDO?

Comment: Your HTML code is not well-formed. All `<li>` elements must be contained in a `<ul>` (or ol / menu) element. Also, if you open a child element inside of a parent element you are required to close the child first before closing the parent. You will notice that both issues exist inside of your main-cat class.

Comment: @kojow7 I only know mysql.

Comment: There are some good resources (google or youtube) that will tell you how to migrate easily from mysql to mysqi. The mysql functions have been deprecated for nearly 3 years and have been completely removed from the latest version of PHP. If you want your application to work in the future you will need to switch to mysqli or PDO.

Comment: @kojow7 Thank you very much. I'm going to study it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the unique category list of array,as like this

```
  $row       = mysql_fetch_assoc($getitems);
  $uniqueCategory  = array_unique($row['category']);
  $uniqueCategoryCount=count($uniqueCategory);

for($i=0;$i< $uniqueCategoryCount;$i++)
{
    echo "</ul><li>$uniqueCategory[$i]</li><ul>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getitems)){
    $category    = $row['category'];
    $name        = $row['name'];
    if($uniqueCategory[i]==$row['category']){
    echo "<li>$name</li>";
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It really help me a lot.